# PHP validation resets the form fields

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
if($domain==""){
    $error="<h4>Enter Domain </h4>";    
}elseif($fname == ""){
    $error="<h4>Enter Firstname </h4>"; 
}elseif($sname == "")
{
    $error="<h4 >Enter Surname</h4>";   
}elseif($tel=="")
{
    $error="<h4 >Enter telephono no</h4>";  
}
else {

$sql11=mysql_query("INSERT INTO domain VALUES('','$domain','$fname','$sname','$tel','$mobile','$email','$company','$address','$city','$country','$pcode','$tele',
'$fax','$qus','$ans')");
echo $sql;
$db->query($sql);

    }
    }
<div><?php echo $error; ?></div>
<form action="" method="post" name="classic_form" id="classic_form">
<div><h4>Personal details:</h4></div><div style="margin-left: 109px;">
          <div>Domain</div>
    <input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="" />
    <div>First name: </div>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" />
    <div>Surname:</div>
     <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value="" />
     <div>Telephone:</div>
    <input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" value="" />
    <div>Mobile:</div>
    </form>
```

In my registration page, i used php validation. After the user submit the form if it shows validation errors it also resets all the fields. How can i resolve this problem? Without reset the fields i have to show the php validation errors. I also used  in each input value. But it shows 
    "Notice: Undefined index: domain in D:\xampp\htdocs\deena\domainreg.php on line 82" . Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?php echo isset($domain) ? $domain : ''; ?>" />
```

Comment: Don't just output `$domain`, use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent cross site scripting! The code than, would be: `<?php echo isset($domain) ? htmlspecialchars($domain) : ''; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass all your values to php, and send back to html to feed your fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Can you explain me how to do this using a small example

Answer (score 1):

Its not 'resetting your fields' .. Your form is being submitted, hence the page is being reset and fields are therefore *loading* empty. Place the `$_POST[]` values in the field values upon page load:

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?php echo $domain ?>" />
<div>First name: </div>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $fname?>" />
<div>Surname:</div>
 <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value="<?php echo $sname?>" />
 <div>Telephone:</div>
<input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" value="<?php echo $tel?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add the variables to the input values:

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?php echo $domain; ?>" />
```

You should also protect the outputted value, against cross site scripting:

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($domain); ?>" />
```

Comment: If i added the input value as you mentioned I got a notice like this Notice: Undefined index: domain in D:\xampp\htdocs\deena\domainreg.php on line 82

Answer (score 1):

In the value field:

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" 
    value="<?php if(isset($_POST['domain'])){echo $_POST['domain'];} ?>">
```

Didn't test it. But i think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In input tag add the php value as like value="" So that it will echo if the variable is posted or it will show the empty one